# How do I input file line results into an array?

Tags: perl

My code so far only reads lines 1 to 4 and prints them. What I want to do instead of printing them is putting them into an array. So any help would be greatly appreciated. And hopefully just the code since it should be short. I learn much faster looking at full code instead of opening another 50 tabs trying to put multiple concepts together. Hopefully I'll learn this at some point and won't require help.

```
my $x = 1;
my $y = 4;

open FILE, "file.txt" or die "can not open file";
while (<FILE>) {
    print if $. == $x .. $. == $y;
}
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just put each line in an array with `push` :

```
my $x = 1;
my $y = 4;
my @array;
open FILE, "file.txt" or die "can not open file";
while (<FILE>) {
    push (@array, $_) if ($. >= $x || $. <= $y);
}
```

Comment: Aaaannd don't forget to up-vote and/or accept the answer ! :-)

Comment: Weird, he accepted your answer, but didn't vote it up! I am voting it up from my side..)

Answer (score 1):

foreach at the end is just proof it works - note it doesn't ignore blank lines - figured you may want to keep them.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
my $fi;
my $line;
my $i = 0;
my @array;
open($fi, "< file.txt");
while ($line = <$fi>) {
    $array[$i] = $line;
    if ($i == 3)
    {
        last;
    }
    $i++;
}
foreach(@array)
{
    print $_;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you know, you don't need to keep iterating through the file once you've got all the data you need.

```
my $x = 1;
my $y = 4;
my @array;
my $file = 'file.txt';

# Lexical filehandle, three-argument open, meaningful error message
open my $file_h, '<', $file or die "cannot open $file: $!";

while (<$file_h>) {
  push @array $_ if $_ >= $x; # This condition is unnecessary when $x is 1
  last if $. == $y;
}
```